Should The User Suffix Field Display On Case Reports?
I ran into this issue earlier this week and am trying to understand if this is just a me problem or a system problem. On the user record you can populate a suffix for a user in the standard field. Example 'Dan Wooding VIII' (First Name, " ", Last Name, " ", Suffix). If you group by the case owner in a report it displays the suffix value. Example:

If you do the same thing for Accounts it does not display the suffix. Example:

The problem is if you select the Dan value and then drill down Salesforce puts the full value into the filter. Example:

This will now return no records because the owner filter doesn't use suffix just first name last name. It seems inconsistent with the other objects, has anyone seen this behavior before?. It's easy enough to work around if you edit the filter after the fact, but users will have to remember that every time they filter by someone with a suffix.

Possibly related to https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000383284&type=1
